# Std Sort make std::vector invalid

Tags: sorting, std, quicksort

I found a bug in std::sort and in some implementations of QuickSort in particular, I do not know whether the problem is in the algorithm in general.

Essence:

When the elements are less than 16 all the norms, because std::sort uses an insertion sort.

When there are 17 or more elements, then quick sort is used with a restriction on the depth of recursion from the logarithm of the number of elements, but vector has time to deteriorate at the first __introsort_loop iteration.

There is a vector spoilage when many identical elements. Corruption happened by replacement of valid iterators with invalid iterators.

Other containers may break too, I did not check.

An example for simplicity with a vector of type "int", for more complex objects - crash at the time of sorting, because the invalid object is passed to the comparison function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
  int i = left, j = right;
  int tmp;
  int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

  /* partition */

  while (i <= j) {
        while (arr[i] < pivot)
              i++;
        while (arr[j] > pivot)
              j--;
        if (i <= j) {
              tmp = arr[i];
              arr[i] = arr[j];
              arr[j] = tmp;
              i++;
              j--;
        }
  };

  /* recursion */

  if (left < j)
        quickSort(arr, left, j);

      if (i < right)
            quickSort(arr, i, right);
}

int main()
{
  for( int i = 0 ; i < 1 ; i++ )
  {
    //std::vector<int> v({5, 6, 1, 6, 2, 6, 3, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6});//reproducible with this
    std::vector<int> v(19, 6);//reproducible with this also
    std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [&v]( const int & left, const int & right )
                                          {
//                                          std::cout << " left=" << left << ", right=" << right << std::endl;
                                            bool b = left <= right;
                                            return b;
                                          }
              );
//    quickSort(v.data(), 0, v.size());
 for( const auto & result : v )
 {
    std::cout << "results: " << result << std::endl;
 }
  }

  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Can someone encounter this behavior quick sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must save the pivot at beginning class like

void quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
  int i = left, j = right; int pivot=x[left];
after that will work

Comment: I tried to use "int pivot = arr[left];" at quickSort with manual filled vector and auto filling (v(19, 6)). But still vector is corrupted with first zero element.           
"results: 0
results: 6
results: 6
...". What gcc version do you use ?

Comment: I have this code and it works but in Pascal, not in C++, did you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code, and it seems that the problem is with vectors created with the constructor vector(n,val) (The fill constructor). Vectors when manually inserted with 16,17,18 and 19 random elements show no problems.

Comment: Recreating a vector manually with identical values seems to pose no problem too. Definitely a problem with the fill constructor.

Comment: I had problem with manual filled vector. I got after sorting "results: 0, 0, 0,1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6". I had gcc version "gcc version 6.4.0 20180424 (Ubuntu 6.4.0-17ubuntu1~16.04)".  What is yours  ?

Comment: I ran the code again, and it turns out, the code works perfectly fine if the lambda expression is replaced with 'left < right' instead of 'left <= right'. I'm running g++ (tdm-1) 4.9.2 on Windows 10.

Comment: I see, so the root of problem is when two elements are equal, then lambda must return "false", not "true"

Comment: Yeah, the comparator apparently requires **strict weak element ordering**. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Comment: Thank you, I will take it into consideration this to fix my bug. Any way I thought std :: sort more safer, and biggest problem of not "strict weak ordering" will be wrong sorting, but not making vector invalid. I'm disappointed in the current implementation of std :: sort.

Comment: PS: std::stable_sort helped me